# How to collapse accordion control only for small device

Tags: zurb-foundation

I need to put the accordion control on my site. My requirement was in desktop or large device the accordion should be an open state by default. If its the mobile or small device it should be collapsed by default. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with JavaScript and/or jQuery. Write a short script to find out what the viewport width is, and if it is larger than a certain width then simply remove Zurb's accordion classes using jQuery's removeClass() function. If the width is equal to or less than that value use addClass() to add them back again.

The Foundation breakpoint for the mobile layouts is 640px, so use that value so you are in step with any other changes taking place for your mobile layout.

Having done that, than you now have complete freedom to restyle the accordion HTML as you wish - firstly, of course, setting display:block in the CSS for all the accordion's content divs, so they all show. But you will probably want to re-style the accordion bar captions as well. Your CSS for all that should be in a media query `@media all and (min-width: 641) {...}` so that it only affects things in medium and large screens.

The Foundation classes to remove are (at least in Foundation 5, I don't know about the earlier versions): on the ul or dl element - "accordion", and 
  on the li or dd elements - "accordion-navigation".
So at 641 widths and above you want:

```
$("ul").removeClass( "accordion");
$("li").removeClass( "accordion-navigation");
```

and similarly with addClass at <= 640. (NB: Don't try to addClass to $("ul.accordion") because, of course, it won't recognise that selector as the class has been removed!

I think that's everything. I just did that in a client's site a few weeks ago, so I know it works!